# Downloading Files when R Shiny App is running on a Linux Server

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am working on a Shiny app which creates a URL based on user inputs and runs that URL using the browseURL() function. The URL downloads a csv file. The app needs to reside on a Linux server and when I try to run it from the server, it keeps giving me an error. When I run it on my machine, it opens Google Chrome (which is my default web browser) and downloads the csv file in the default "downloads" folder (which is what I expected it to do). Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. Could someone please help me figure out why it works on my machine but not on the Linux server? I just started this project and I don't know about Linux servers. The errors look like -

```
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
   
   # Application title
   titlePanel("Testing File Download on Linux Server"),
   
   
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         textInput("SID","Specify SIDs", value = ""),
         actionBttn("goButton","Go!",color = "default",style = "unite",size = "lg")
      ),
      
      mainPanel()
      
           
   )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
 ts_info<-eventReactive(input$goButton,{
   TS_url<-paste("http://xyzserver&request=getList&station_no=",input$SID,"&format=csv&downloadfilename=testingdownload",sep="")

   return(TS_url)   
   

 })
 observe({
   browseURL(ts_info())
 }) 
   
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using browseURL you are asking to open a web browser on the server which obviously is not able to do because it's not the place to do this. The browser must be launched on your computer, not the server.

You can format and provide the url as an uiOutput

```
sidebarPanel(
         textInput("SID","Specify SIDs", value = ""),
         actionBttn("goButton","Go!",color = "default",style = "unite",size = "lg"),
         uiOutput("dlLink")
      ),
```

```
output$dlLink <- renderUI(tags$a(href=tsInfo(),"Download"))
```

Comment: @ Billy34 - Thank you. I understand what you are saying however, this was a simplified version of what I am trying to so. I am only interested in the downloaded file as I read it in the app later and analyze the data. I do not want to provide a link for the users to download the file. Is there a way to just download the file without the user clicking on any button? Also, based on how many SIDs the user specifies, I have a loop i.e. for each SID the app will create a URL and download a data file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't think it's possible as otherwise any page can download any files without your consent to your computer opening the path for virus dissemination. You can push things form server to the displayed page but writing them to the disk will need (if possible) more rights. I'm afraid it's beyond my expertise :-)

Comment: You can use browser's local storage (it's a key value database managed like cookies and cache). Dean Attali has wrote a comprehensive intro https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html